# Getting "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" while table does exist

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, errors

I'm fairly new to Oracle database. I have installed `Oracle Database 11g R2` on `Oracle Linux 6`. I have successfully created a new database with `dbca` and connected to the database using:

```
$ sqlplus "/ as sysdba"
```

I successfully created a table and inserted some data and performed some selects:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Instructors (
         tid    NUMBER(7) PRIMARY KEY,
         fname  VARCHAR2(32),
         lname  VARCHAR2(32),
         tel    NUMBER(16),
         adrs   VARCHAR2(128) );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO Instructors (tid, fname, lname, tel, adrs)
     VALUES (8431001, 'John', 'Smith', 654321, 'London');

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT count(*) FROM Instructors;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        1
```

Then I created a new user with the CONNECT privilege:

```
SQL> CREATE USER teacher1 IDENTIFIED BY pass1;

User created.

SQL> GRANT CONNECT TO teacher1;

Grant succeeded.
```

Then I created a new role with appropriate object privileges:

```
SQL> CREATE ROLE instructor;

Role created.

SQL> GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON Instructors TO instructor;

Grant succeeded.
```

And granted the role to the user:

```
SQL> GRANT instructor TO teacher1;

Grant succeeded.
```

Next I exited sqlplus with `exit;` and connected as the new user to test it. I logged in successfully to the database with:

```
$ sqlplus teacher1

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Jul 25 03:20:50 2013
Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: *****

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

But when I try to select from the table it says:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM Instructors;
SELECT * FROM Instructors
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

What I'm missing here ?!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You created the table in the `SYS` schema (which you should **never**, ever do. Really, ***never***).

When you log in as `teacher1` any statement looks for objects in that schema. But there is no `TEACHER1.INSTRUCTORS` table, because the real name is `SYS.INSTRUCTORS` (did I mention what a **bad** idea it is to create objects in the SYS schema?).

You need to run `select * from sys.instructors` to get access to that table. If you don't want to prefix the table name with the schema, create a synonym in the `teacher1` schema:

```
create synonym teacher1.instructors for sys.instructors;
```

Then `teacher1` can access the table from the `SYS` schema without fully qualifying it.

Again: stop using the SYS or SYSTEM account for anything that is not DBA stuff. Use a regular account for that.

Comment: Thanks. I have to create tables that multiple users could access it. From your explanation, I infer that I should create a new user such as `dbadmin` with `DBA` privileges, and create all the tables with this DBA user. Then all other users should access the tables from the `DBADMIN` schema ... Correct ?!

Comment: @SeyedMohammad: No need to create a DBA user. Create a regular user and create the tables in that schema. Then grant select on those tables to the other users. Using DBA roles for anything else than DBA work is not a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

my answer is just write table name with login credentials of "sys" or/and "xe"
like
for my program change
ur table name is EMP then write XE.EMP
like "select * from XE.EMP"